# Making a control "transparent" to click events

Tags: wpf, events, listbox

I have a ListBox displaying some items, and in certain modes I "stamp" a kind of watermark across the top of it. I've done this with a Border containing a TextBlock with an Opacity of 0.5. All this works nicely.

However, I still want the user to be able to click on the items in the ListBox but if I click on the "stamp" it obviously eats the click events and they're not seen by the ListBox.

What do I have to do to prevent this? (i.e. allow the ListBox to see the Click event)

Thanks,

Craig

Comment: Could you please show how exactly you do this stamp?

Comment: See the example below - this is pretty much what I'm doing.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can do this with the [IsHitTestVisible](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.ishittestvisible.aspx) property:

```
<Grid xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <ListBox>
        <ListBoxItem>a</ListBoxItem>
        <ListBoxItem>b</ListBoxItem>
        <ListBoxItem>c</ListBoxItem>
    </ListBox>
    <Border Opacity="0.2" Background="Cyan" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="5" IsHitTestVisible="False" >
        <TextBlock Text="EXAMPLE" FontSize="20" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
    </Border>
</Grid>
```